# For which $p$, does there exist an anti-derivative?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, derivatives, analytic-functions, cauchy-integral-formula

For positive integer $p$, consider the holomorphic function

$f(z)=\frac{\sin (z)}{z^p}$ , for $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ .

For which  values of $p$ , does there exist a holomorphic function $g:\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}\to \mathbb{C}$   such that $g'(z)=f(z)$ for $z\in 
 \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}?$

$(1)$ All even integers .

$(2)$ All odd integers.

$(3)$ All multiples of $3$.

$(4)$ All multiples of $4$.

My thinking :- I am aware of the fact "Every analytic function on a simply connected domain has a primitive (anti-derivative)"

Here , the domain is not simply connected and I am not sure how else to proceed.

Please give a hint. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Consider the series expansion of $\sin$. Note that monomial functions of the form $z \mapsto z^n$ have an anti-derivative (on $\Bbb C \setminus \{0\}$) iff $n \neq -1$.
(Convergence issues aside) This tells you that you need to pick a $p$ such that there is no $1/z$ term. After this, show that all such $p$ actually do give a function with an anti-derivative.

Comment: So you mean that the series obtained by term by term integration gives us the required primitive after properly choosing $p$ (which are actually odd integers) ?

Comment: Yes. You would have to show that that actually converges and is an anti-derivative of $\sin x/x^p$. If you know basic facts about convergence of (anti)derivatives of power series, this should be easy.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani But there $p$ is fixed at one time ... please can you explain yours solution  little more?

Comment: @neelkanth: Note that $$\frac{\sin(z)}{z^p} = \frac{z}{z^p} - \frac{1}{3!}\frac{z^3}{z^p} + \cdots.$$ Simply pick those $p$ for which there is no $1/z$ in the above expansion.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani But if I choose p as $3$ then there are such terms

Comment: @AryamanMaithani how all odds works ?

Comment: If $p=3$ the it is like $\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{3!}+\cdots$

Comment: @neelkanth: and that function given does have an anti-derivative, simply take the anti-derivative term by term (one can do that for power series).

Comment: @AryamanMaithani ok ok now I got .... thank you ...

Comment: This answer was very helpful for me, however, I have a beginner's doubt, when we take the antiderivative(integrate) term by term, we get $1/z$ from $1/z^{2}$ and there it is; the term $1/z$ but when we take even integers then after integrating we get $log z$, so my question is, do we not want the term $log z$ or $1/z$ and why? Please explain. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: @USER0117: Yes, you are correct that we do not want $1/z$ in our expansion. This is because $1/z$ does not have an antiderivative on $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$. ($\log$ is not a suitable candidate because you cannot define it holomorphically on $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$.)

Comment: Thanks so much, I get it. Also, $1/z$ too leads to infinity, does that not create a problem?

Comment: @USER0117: That does not create an issue since $0$ is not in the domain. In general, there is no reason for the function to be bounded.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! Now, I get it.